# Java read text file in lines, but seperate words in lines into array

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a code that looks at a text file, and does a while loop so that it reads each line, but I need each word per line to be in an array so I can carry out some if statements. The problem I am having at the moment is that my array is currently storing all the words in the file in an array.. instead of all the words per line in array.

Here some of my current code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    List<String> listwords = new ArrayList<>();


while (in.hasNext()) {
      listwords.addAll(Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split(" ")));
}


    if(listwords.get(4) == null){
        name = listwords.get(2);
     }
    else {
        name = listwords.get(4);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an *array* of strings per line, then write like this instead:

```
List<String[]> listwords = new ArrayList<>();

while (in.hasNext()) {
    listwords.add(in.nextLine().split(" "));
}
```

Btw, you seem to be using the term "array" and "ArrayList" interchangeably.
That would be a mistake, they are distinct things.

If you want to have an *`List`* of strings per line, then write like this instead:

```
List<List<String>> listwords = new ArrayList<>();

while (in.hasNext()) {
    listwords.add(Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split(" ")));
}
```

Comment: Ok great the first solution is what I am looking for, however many of the varaibles I am assigning, which are of type string, now show the error message: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String... so what can fix this issue?

Comment: @madhaj1 your follow-up question is unclear. And it would be better to ask a new question on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`listwords.addAll(Arrays.asList(in.nextLine().split("\\r?\\n")));`

to split on new Lines. Then you can split these further on the Whitespace, if you want.