# How can read a txt file so that all words are placed in a new array element and not every new line is placed in a element?

Tags: java

I currently have written a code that is able to read through a .txt file and for every new line it will be placed in a array element (not very hard). It works but this was not my initial intention, I want to have every word placed in a new array element, not after every new line. Here is my current code, can someone maybe help? Thank you!

```
public static ArrayList<String> read_file() {

        try {
            ArrayList<String> data_base = new ArrayList<String>();

            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Jcool\\OneDrive\\A Levels\\Computer Science\\CSV files\\data convert\\convert.txt"));
            while(s1.hasNextLine()) {
                data_base.add(s1.nextLine());
            }
            return data_base;

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: use the split method with space as a separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read all the lines at once and split them into array.

```
private static String readAllBytes(String filePath) 
{
    String content = "";
    try
    {
        content = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(filePath) ) );
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

Create a method named **readAllBytes** and call it like this;

```
    /* String to split. */
    String stringToSplit = readAllBytes(filePath);
    String[] tempArray;

    /* delimiter */
    String delimiter = " ";//space if its a file contains words

    /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
    tempArray = stringToSplit.split(delimiter);
```

If you mean to split your lines into array check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618480/1367450) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [split(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. It returns a `String[]`. As an example

```java
String string = "AAA-BBB";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // AAA
String part2 = parts[1]; // BBB
```